# Finding Matrix of T with respect to basis.

Tags: matrices, vectors, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

$\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 11  \\ 4 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ represents a linear transformation $T:$$\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the basis, ${[(3,1),(0,2)]}$. Find the matrix of $T$ with respect to basis ${[(1,1),(-1,1)]}$

There is some problem with the approach I'm employing, I'm not sure what. I am a little confused with these tyeles of questions are to be approached. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of basis matrix from $\bigl((1,1),(-1,1)\bigr)$ to $\bigl((3,1),(0,2)\bigr)$ is$$P=\begin{bmatrix}\frac13&\frac13\\\frac13&-\frac23\end{bmatrix}.$$So, the answer to your problem is the matrix$$P^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}-2&11\\4&2\end{bmatrix}P=\begin{bmatrix}8&-16\\1&-8\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Shouldn't the basis change from the second to the first? I'm sorry, my concepts are a bit shaky.

Comment: I understand now. That was a stupid doubt. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.